# Get the resource folder path of an image

Tags: c#

I ask because I already searched everywhere without finding results...

I already try these two methods:

```
//first attempt
  Var filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly (). Location + @"\..\..\Resources\Image.jpg";

//Second attempt
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly (). GetManifestResourceNames ();
```

Already probe these methods in which they did not give results I only need to obtain the route of an image of my project.
help please.

Comment: All those double backslashes and spaces in your path string are going to throw off your results.

Comment: There is no Resource folder in a deployed app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Build Action of your item is set to Embedded Resource.

You might find these two methods useful, pass in the `name` of the resource and a list of `assemblies` -- it'll search the assemblies in order which provides a simple override resource capability

```
    private static Tuple<Assembly, string> FindEmbeddedResource(string name, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(r => r.EndsWith(name));

            if (resourceName != null)
            {
                return new Tuple<Assembly, string>(assembly, resourceName);
            }
        }

        return new Tuple<Assembly, string>(null, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the embedded resource scanning assemblies in the order supplied. Allows APIs to override library assets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
    /// <param name="assemblies">The assemblies.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string GetEmbeddedResource(string name, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        var embeddedResource = FindEmbeddedResource(name, assemblies);
        var assembly = embeddedResource.Item1;
        var resource = embeddedResource.Item2;

        if (assembly != null)
        {
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            using (var textStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                resource = textStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return resource;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I find only the name in a variable?

Comment: If your `Image.jpg` is an Embedded Resource then you can use `yourAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` to find out what the compiler decided to call it.